# How to change background color in single ZK Grid Cells?

Tags: java, grid, cell, background-color, zk

Anyone got any idea how to change the background color of a cell in a ZK grid? Been searching the web for several hours and can't find much. A static cell wouldn't be a problem, but this is a dynamically rendered grid.

Plan is to colour certain cells red or yellow because I want to highlight that specific value.

My Zul:

```
<?page title="Ergebnis des Clusterings" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns:n="native" xmlns:c="client">
    <style>body { background-color: #fcfcfc; }</style>
    <image id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/dL3ahNV.gif"
        style="display: block; width: 300px; margin: 1% auto 0 auto;">
    </image>
    <window id="win" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        style="margin: 0 auto; background: #ddf4ea; position: relative;"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('frontend.ClusteringOutputVM')"
        border="normal" width="1000px" position="center,top"
        mode="embedded">
        <caption label="KaufDort Cluster - Clustering Output"
            style="font-family: Segoe UI; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px; color: #000000; padding: 5px;" />
        <include style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"
            src="marketing.zul" />
        <hbox>
            <grid id="grid" model="@load(vm.mapModel)" hflex="max">
                <columns children="@load(vm.columnsModel)">
                    <template name="children">
                        <column hflex="min" label="@load(each)"
                            sort="none"
                            style="background: #ddf4ea; font-family: Segoe UI; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;" />
                    </template>
                </columns>
                <template name="model" var="cur_row">
                    <row
                        children="@load(vm.columnsModel) @template(forEachStatus.index lt (vm.columnsModel.size()- cur_row.value.size()) ? 'fixed' : 'variable')">
                        <template name="fixed">
                            <cell>
                                <button label="@load(cur_row.key)"
                                    style="border: none; border-radius: 0px; background: #7f8c8d; color: white; text-shadow: none; font-size: 18px;"
                                    onClick="@command('showDiagram')" width="100%" />
                            </cell>
                        </template>

                        <template name="variable">
                            <cell>
                                <label
                                    style="text-align: left; font-family: Segoe UI; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;"
                                    value="@load(cur_row.value[forEachStatus.index- vm.columnsModel.size()+ cur_row.value.size()])" />
                            </cell>
                        </template>
                    </row>
                </template>
            </grid>
                
            <image id="questionmark" src="Files/QuestionmarkButton.png"
                tooltip="centroid" style="cursor: help" />
              
        </hbox>
    </window>
    <popup id="centroid" width="300px">
        <html>
            <![CDATA[ Text]]>
        </html>
    </popup>
</zk>
```

My VM:

```
public class ClusteringOutputVM {

    private ArrayList<KMeansCluster> clusterList;
    private ArrayList<Feature> featureList;
    private int numOfClusters;
    private ListModelMap data;
    private ListModel columns_model;
    private boolean[][] paintMe;
    @Wire
    private Grid grid;

    public ClusteringOutputVM() {

        data = new ListModelMap();
        columns_model = new ListModelList();

        getSessionGlobalVariables();
        transferDataToListModelMap();
        fillColumnsModel(numOfClusters);
    }

    @AfterCompose
    public void paintCells() {
        for (int i = 0; i < paintMe.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < paintMe[i].length; j++) {
                if(paintMe[i][j]){
                    grid.getCell(i, j); ?????
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void transferDataToListModelMap() {
        List<String> valueList = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
        int featureType = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < featureList.size(); i++) {
            featureType = featureList.get(i).getFeatureType();
            if (featureType == 0) {
                NumericFeature nf = (NumericFeature) featureList.get(i);
                double mean = nf.getMean();
                double stDev = nf.getStdDev();

                for (int j = 0; j < clusterList.size(); j++) {
                    Instance in = clusterList.get(j).getCentroid();
                    String centroidVal = in.toString(i);
                    double value = Double.valueOf(centroidVal);
                    if (value > (mean + stDev) || value < (mean - stDev)) {
                        paintMe[i+1][j+1] = true;
                    }
                    valueList.add(centroidVal);

                }
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < clusterList.size(); j++) {
                    Instance in = clusterList.get(j).getCentroid();
                    paintMe[i+1][j+1] = false;
                    valueList.add(in.toString(i));
                }

                data.put((featureList.get(i).getFeatureName()), valueList);
                valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
        }

    }

    private void getSessionGlobalVariables() {
        clusterList = (ArrayList<KMeansCluster>) Sessions.getCurrent()
                .getAttribute("finalClusterList");
        featureList = (ArrayList<Feature>) Sessions.getCurrent().getAttribute(
                "finalFeatureList");
        numOfClusters = (int) Sessions.getCurrent().getAttribute(
                "chosenNumOfClusters");
        paintMe = new boolean[featureList.size() + 1][clusterList.size() + 1];
    }

    private void fillColumnsModel(int endValue) {
        ((List) columns_model).add(new String("Feature"));
        for (int i = 1; i <= endValue; ++i)
            ((List) columns_model).add(new String("Cluster " + i));

    }

    public ListModel getColumnsModel() {
        return columns_model;
    }

    public ListModel getMapModel() {
        return data;
    }

    @Command
    public void showDiagram(
            @ContextParam(ContextType.COMPONENT) Component component) {

        Button b = (Button) component;
        String featureChosen = b.getLabel();
        Feature feat = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < featureList.size(); i++) {
            if (featureList.get(i).getFeatureName().equals(featureChosen)) {
                feat = featureList.get(i);
            }
        }
        Sessions.getCurrent().setAttribute("chosenFeature", feat);

        if (feat.getFeatureType() != 0)
            // koennte problematisch werden bei anderen Browsern
            Executions.getCurrent().sendRedirect("stackedColumns.zul");
        else
            Executions.getCurrent().sendRedirect("boxplot.zul");

    }

}
```

Comment: On what condition need your cell to be colored?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

You are in MVVM so `@Wire` will not work unless to wire the selectors.
I specific don't say how to do it because it's bad practice to do.

Just work MVVM :

```
<cell style="@load(each.condition?'some style':'some other style')"/>
```

If you can't acces that, you can always make a wrapper class what contains all the value's in stead of the `Boolean[][]` separated.

Answer (score 0):

As chillworld said, @Wire does not work by default when using ViewModel. Read [here](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/advanced/wire_components.html) how to do it, but note that it is discouraged.

The better solution in this context to put some `ParamObject` in your `valueList` for each row instead of just strings:

```
class ParamObject {
    private String label;
    private String sClass; // or style
    // getters and setters
}
```

Create it in your `ViewModel.transferDataToListModelMap()`:

```
Instance in = clusterList.get(j).getCentroid();
String centroidVal = in.toString(i);
double value = Double.valueOf(centroidVal);

ParamObject params = new ParamObject();
params.setLabel(centroidVal);
params.setSclass(value > (mean + stDev) || value < (mean - stDev) ? "colored" : "notColored")
valueList.add(params);
```

You can then use data binding in your zul:

```
<label sclass="cur_row.value[weird index calculation].sClass"
       style="your inline style for font"
       value="@load(cur_row.value[weird index calculation].label)" />
```

You might want to store the index in a [temporary field](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/ref.html) to keep it readable.

You can then write some sClasses for your style. If you prefer to do it with inline style instead, just concat it with the font styling you have already and bind the sClass/style attribute of your `ParamObject` against `style` instead of `sclass`.